# Delay the delivery of an email (outlook)

Tags: outlook

simple question: **Does Outlook has to be open to deliver a delayed email?**

Greetings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only if you are using a POP or IMAP account.  Outlook can be closed and the email will still send at the scheduled time if you're using an Exchange/Office 365 account.